# Always Unauthorize Jwt-auth Laravel

Tags: laravel, jwt

I have `AuthController`

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $user = UserSistem::create([
        'username' => $request->username,
        'nama' => $request->nama,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password_secret' => bcrypt($request->password)
    ]);

    $token = auth()->login($user);

    return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);

    if (!$token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}

protected function respondWithToken($token)
{
    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $token,
        'token_type' => 'bearer'
    ]);
}
```

`register` function is work, but not for `login`, should I use `password` column instead of `password_secret` in `register` function, because I try to use `password` column and work fine?

how can I use `password_secret` column on payload at `register` function?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the JWT then pass the credentials to JWT Object

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
  $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
   try {
    if (!$token =  JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);

} catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong
return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }
}

return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}
```

Comment: I mean, how I can use `password_secret` instead of `password` ?

Comment: Either you can change the password _secret to password in your database or you can change the password field to password_secret in your login form.

Comment: I have a table user with `password_secret` field in my current database, I can't change it. I mean, it's requirement from my client.

Comment: Ok then You can replace password with password_secret  in login form

Comment: You mean I should use `password_secret` in parameters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180497/discussion-between-gurpal-singh-and-itx).